# How do i enable 2-legged oauth for a social sign device (Smiirl) use case to display number of followers. #linkedin

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api, clientcredential

For marketing purposes we purchased a custom physical counter device ([www.smiirl.com](http://www.smiirl.com)) and would like it to show in real time the number of followers to our organization on linkedin.

We would like to use the  Organization Network Size API (Follower Count) to show the number of followers for our organization (https://www.smiirl.com, https://help.smiirl.com/article/133-what-should-i-do-to-enable-my-custom-counter-to-display-a-number).

Without any human involvement, we would like this sign to be able to pull organizational followers from the LinkedIn API , thus we would need to use
create Client credential (2-legged) authentication tokens that we would need for this use case.

At this moment, its not possible to create 2-legged tokens, either through the LinkedIn Authentication API or through the developer portal (https://developer.linkedin.com), this option is disabled in the portal and the API endpoints says that "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"

Is there any other products and programs we need to enable to make this work ?

Does Marketing Developer Platform (MDP) support this use case ?
Do we need to order MDP with "LinkedIn Marketing Developer Platform Access Form" through the developer portal to enable this ? Is it a supported use case for MDP ?

References:

Getting Access
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access

Application Authorization(2-legged authorization):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authentication

#linkedin